# Azure Virtual Machine error: Unable to Capture Image: "Endpoint Not found

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am getting the error as below in my Azure Virtual Machine when I save my vhd:-

```
Failed to capture image vmvhdtrialacc of virtual machine vmvhdalpha

Endpoint Not found: There was no endpoint listening at https://management.core.windows.net:8443/*GUID*/services/hostedservices/vmvhdalpha/deployments/vmvhdalpha/roleInstances/vmvhdalpha/Operations that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your problem is a recently known issue with Windows Azure Virtual Machines,  described as "still investigating status", in the following [Windows Azure Virtual Machine Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/threads):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/29fc7e72-6c95-4704-bf79-b9aba562c6ad

My suggestion will be to submit your issues in the same forum and track the status of your problem in the above link.

Comment: How long it will take to find the fix of this problem?

Comment: If it is urgent for your go ahead and delete your VM and then VHD associated with it and then create a new VM. (i do not have any idea how long it will take to get a fix for such problem)

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough I had a running VM, then added an SSL cert to a separate Cloud Service via the portal, and that seemed to doom my VM.  It went into a stopped state, and when trying to start it received the error above.  Only solution as mentioned in prior post's links, delete the VM (or delete the VM and clone new one from VHD).